# How to send variable in action java class to jquery?

Tags: java, jquery, jsp

When I click on the button will be equal to the amount of undefind while the amount is equal to 1
in jsp page :

```
<%
  String err1 = (String) request.getAttribute("err2");
  int code = 0;

       if (err1 != null){
       code = Integer.parseInt(err1);        
         System.out.println("  code  " + code);
       }
%>
<button type="button" id="btnok">ok</button>
 <br />
    <%if(code == 3){ %>
        <input id="txtcode" type="hidden" value="1" />
    <%}%>
<br />
```

in jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#btnok").click(function(event) {
       var xxx = $("#txtcode").val();
       alert("xxx  1  test  + " + xxx);
});
});
```

Comment: check that your `if` condition is getting true and you are getting `txtcode` in your html source code

Comment: What does "_the amount of undefind_" mean?

Comment: @Vohuman the amount of undefind = input text value is undefind

Comment: Input value can't be `undefined`. jQuery `val` returns `undefined` when the collection is empty, or the first element in the collection doesn't have `value` property.

Comment: If you are asking "Why `xxx` is equal to `undefined` when it should be `"1"`", check the DOM and make sure the element exists in your document.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely reason is that the condition:

```
<%if(code == 3){ %>
    <input id="txtcode" type="hidden" value="1" />
<%}%>
```

is not being met and the `input` is not being inserted to the DOM. Reload the page and view the page source to see if the input is inserted.